# Couldn't flag a question as off-topic

Tags: support, flags, off-topic

I found a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144626/slick-grid-functionality) in Meta Stack Overflow which was completely *off-topic* (The question was for Stack Overflow.). So I clicked on flag. But I could not find any option to tick it as *off-topic*. See this:

> [image]

Is it a bug or anything else ?

Comment: It was probably deleted after you loaded the page, but before you loaded the flag menu.

Comment: Can you link to the question?

Comment: Yes [see this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144626/slick-grid-functionality). For me it is *Page Not Found*.

Comment: It was closed and deleted by a moderator 14 hours ago.

Comment: After I could not found off-topic option I tick *other* option. And wrote "It is off topic." And seeing my *Flagging Summary* it is helpful flag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was deleted after you loaded the page, but before you loaded the flag menu.

This happens quite often for me. When another one of those off topic questions gets posted (usually by someone who's question banned) The close race begins.

Every once in a while, I manage to load the page while the question is still open. But before I can flag it, it gets mod-hammered and insta-deleted. When you load the flag menu, the close options are missing because the question is already closed/deleted.

When you refresh the page the question is already deleted, "This question was removed from Meta Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation."

Comment: Oh yes. I realized the same when I refreshed the page.

Answer (score 3):

If the option you wanted to flag as is missing, your first reaction should be to close the dialog and refresh the page, as something has probably happened to the post since you loaded the page and decided to click that button. **Don't** just use the other field to explain your reason anyways. This just adds an unnecessary flag to the queue that needs to be reviewed.